# React Router v5 always redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to handle unmatched routes in my app by having them redirect to the login screen, I've set my routes up like so:

```
<Switch>
{
    session.IsLoggedIn === false &&
    <Container fluid className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <Route exact path="/" component={ Login } />
        <Route path="/ResetPassword/:token" component={ ResetPassword } />      
        <Redirect to="/" />
    </Container>
}
</Switch>
```

With this setup though, even if I enter a legitimate route, i.e `/ResetPassword/3245924`, it still redirects to the login screen.

Note: I've gotten the above setup by following this tutorial: https://www.surajsharma.net/blog/react-router-default-route

How would I ensure that the legitimate routes are hit while redirecting on non handled routes?

Answer (score 0):

For best practice, all default paths should lead to your landing page...Routing during runtime is supposed to be managed by React backend. You could look into service workers for your own proxy. I suggest you remove the:    `session.IsLoggedIn === false &&` and just use a regular route initialization ...and use useState or onComponentDidMount to automatically load the content you want- you can make that page a component.   oh my apologies for the confusion, I'm glad you got this resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You doesnt have wrapped your redirect in default router, therefore it will be always rendered/triggered

for correct behaviour wrap it in "default" route

```
<Switch>
{
    session.IsLoggedIn === false &&
    <Container fluid className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <Route exact path="/" component={ Login } />
        <Route path="/ResetPassword/:token" component={ ResetPassword } />      
        <Route path="*"><Redirect to="/" /></Route>
    </Container>
}
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately, this doesn't work either, it still wont let me navigate to the resetpassword route.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue out, it seems to be because the `<Container>` element was housing the routes, not the `<Switch>` element. When I moved the `<Switch>` element into the `<Container>`, making the `<Route>` elements direct descendants of the  element it worked.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `Switch` component ***exclusively*** renders the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` component. When it hits anything other than one of these two components, i.e. the `Container`, it stops matching and just renders *that* component/element. Once *not* rendered directly by a `Switch`, all `Route` and `Redirect` components are ***inclusively*** matched and rendered. The `Redirect` component doesn't have a `from` prop so it will ***always*** be matched and effect a navigation change.

## Solution

Since the `Switch` isn't rendering any `Route` or `Redirect` components it appears it's unnecessary where it is currently. Move it *into* the conditional rendering to directly wrap the routing components.

```
{!session.IsLoggedIn &&
  <Container fluid className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/ResetPassword/:token" component={ResetPassword} />      
      <Route path="/" component={Login} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  </Container>
}
```

Technically speaking, the path `"/"` is *already* a path-prefix for ***every*** other route path, so the `Redirect` isn't actually reachable. You should be able to remove it since `path="/"` will catch and match anything that wasn't already matched prior to it.

```
{!session.IsLoggedIn &&
  <Container fluid className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/ResetPassword/:token" component={ResetPassword} />      
      <Route path="/" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  </Container>
}
```